# Famo.us' Scrollview pagination: How to snap only when NEAR an edge?

Tags: famo.us

The Famo.us Scrollview has a pagination feature that allows you to snap to the closest item.

Imagine you have a small container which has items with lots of content.

As soon as you want to scroll down to read the content outside the container, it either snaps back to the top, or snaps to the next item.

Does anybody know how to activate pagination only within a thresshold (X pixels) of an edge? That would be awesome.

Codepen demonstrating the problem here: http://codepen.io/markmarijnissen/pen/AGxaC?editors=001

```
var scroll = new Scrollview({
  paginated: true,
  pagePeriod: 500,
  pageStopSpeed: 0.01,   // mysterious option which might provide solution
  pageSwitchSpeed: 100,  // mysterious option which might provide solution
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/master/views/Scrollview.js

The TOLERANCE constant is not configurable yet. But you could easily contribute to make it configurable ;)